# Windows FORMS for Intranet instead of Web Based

Tags: winforms

Can we implement a enterprise wide intranet application completely with WinForms instead of Browser based Web apps?
What are pros and cons and which is preferred over other?

Answer (score 3):

Some stuff on my mind:

#### WinForms Pros

- Richer user experience
- More responsive
- Usually easier to write interactive processes

#### Web App Pros

- Centralized maintenance (easy to update, ...)
- Centralized data access security
- Easier to access over the Internet and on the go
- Does not rely on anything except a browser on the client (so the client platform doesn't matter)

Comment: All authentication to the intranet is done with Windows Authentication. I am referring to Intranet apps and none of your points strongly suggest why I cannot use Winform for Intranet

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't use it. Which is better depends on the specific circumstance. I just mentioned some key points to consider.

Answer (score 3):

We developed a lot of winforms apps at the place I used to work. [ClickOnce](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022092503/http://geekswithblogs.net/gpro/archive/2008/03/16/clickonce-winforms-deployment-part-1.aspx) made things a lot easier in the case of deployment.